# Is there documentation/an API for the PBix file format?

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi

We have large csv files in Azure Blobs that we want to report on.
It looks like with some M, we can use Power BI desktop to connect to the blobs and start to report on them.

We want to automate this process so I guess an option is to create our own pbix files and upload them.

Ideally, there would be a better Power BI API where we could configure the data sources server side in the same way as the desktop.

I've looked and the pbix files are zips with DataMashup also being a zip (standard openx files like docx).

Does anyone know of a NuGet package or details on how I could create dashboard in the latest Power BI using c#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file format is not documented. We're working towards allowing you to create reports and dashboards programmatically, but there's no timeline on that yet that I can share. Right now, you should be able to use power query to load the file in question and then upload that to the power bi service to share within your team. Would suggest adding a request at support.powerbi.com so we can get back to you when we've added what you need.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. I've been talking to @Tom and looking forward to some of the features that are coming. https://support.powerbi.com/forums/268152-developer-apis/suggestions/6856183-provide-api-library-to-create-local-pbix-files

Comment: Any update on this? We would find this really useful.

Comment: @Lukasz P. Any update on this? Looking at doing something very similar.